# What are the prohibited numbers in android dialer app?

Tags: java, android, android-source

Learning the source code of [Android Dialpad Fragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/master/src/com/android/dialer/dialpad/DialpadFragment.java) I've noticed quite strange thing - you can not call several numbers.

```
if (number != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mProhibitedPhoneNumberRegexp)
    && number.matches(mProhibitedPhoneNumberRegexp)) {
    Log.i(TAG, "The phone number is prohibited explicitly by a rule.");
if (getActivity() != null) {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = 
    ErrorDialogFragment.newInstance(
        R.string.dialog_phone_call_prohibited_message);
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "phone_prohibited_dialog");
}
```

where the `mProhibitedPhoneNumberRegexp` should be loaded as

```
mProhibitedPhoneNumberRegexp = getResources().getString(
    R.string.config_prohibited_phone_number_regexp);
```

But I can't find the related string in dailer module and not in the PhoneCommen module and not in the Contacts module of the Android source. So my question is where to find this String, why Android OS prohibits to dial some numbers, is it White House or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default in this file:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/master/res/values/donottranslate_config.xml?autodive=0%2F%2F

As you can see, it is empty.

Comment: any idea why it is reserved ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Maybe a legal issue?